# Replace content of span with JS

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have multiple span elements:
`<span class="sac-chat-name">username : </span>`

I want to remove the first space before the colon.

I tried it with JS like this:

```
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("sac-chat-name");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  y[i].replace(" : ", ": ");
}
```

but this doesn't work:

`Uncaught TypeError: y[i].replace is not a function …`

Where is the error?

Comment: because an dom element node is not the element's text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues in your code:

1. You are using the element itself not the text content, you have to use the text using `innerText` or `textContent`.
2. *The [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method **returns** a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement*. You have to reassign the elements text content by the retuned result of `replace()`:

```js
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("sac-chat-name");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  y[i].textContent = y[i].textContent.replace(" : ", ": ");
}
```

```html
<span class="sac-chat-name">username : </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

the JavaScript replace method is a string prototype. With that being said you cannot use it on nodes.

```js
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("sac-chat-name");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  // get the current content 
  var curText = y[i].innerHTML;
  // sanitize content
  var sanitized = curText.replace(" : ", ": ");
  // replace content
  y[i].innerHTML = sanitized;
}
```

So first of all you have to get the current Content of your element. You can do this using `innerHTML` after that you can sanitize the string and replace the HTML of your element.

Answer (score 1):

Mamun said right,
you can also go threw an Array, forEach loop is easier to read

```js
var spans = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('sac-chat-name'));
spans.forEach(span => {

   span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replace(" :", ":");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace particular whitespaces in the strings, you can use REGEX as well.

```
 y.textContent.replace(/\s/g,'');
```